# ASP.NET MVC5 launch dynamic file download from jQuery by passing arguments

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In asp mvc 5, I launch a download with that code:

```
//jQuery
 $(document).on('click', "#download_export", function (e) {
        window.location = url_download;
    });

//c#
 public FileResult GetFile()
        {
            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("dfdfdf dfssdfdfs"),
                   "text/plain",
                    "test.txt");
        }
```

It works and trigger a txt file download on client browser.

I want to do same thing by passing file content on argument from controller,

I tried:

```
    $(document).on('click', "#download_export", function (e) {
     $.get(url_download,
            {
                content : 'this is my content'
            }
            , function (data) {
                     console.log('works')
        });
   });

 public FileResult GetFile(string content)
        {
            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content),
                   "text/plain",
                    "test.txt");
        }
```

I saw with debugger that Action is reached but it doesn't trigger a download,

Do you have idea how to do it?

Comment: Here -  `public FileResult GetFile(string content)` - what is the value of content when you debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you cannot download files with ajax. 
Due to security reason, javascript is not allowed to access local files system. Imagine a case where js from a remote site tries to steal files on your pc.

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', "#download_export", function (e) {
        window.location = url_download + "?content=this is my content";
    });
```

Or you can create a hidden iframe on the page to download the file to avoid changing location of current window.

```
$(document).on('click', "#download_export", function (e) {
            $("#yourIframe").attr("src",url_download + "?content=this is my content");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `dynamic download` then you can use -> $.filedownload jquery plugin for those purposes. Simple usage:

```
var promise = $.fileDownload(url_download+"?content=yourContentHere");
```